# concatenate strings to form a URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm designing a Chrome extension and I collect user input which form part of a URL: for example

```
var myTextField = document.getElementById("myTextarea");

window.open("http://www.somewebpage/" + myTextField +  
"/therestofit","this is a new window");
```

However when it executes it inserts:

```
object%20HTMLTextAreaElement
```

into the URL instead of the user supplied component - any advice?

Comment: The input element is not its value. You have to retrieve the value with `.value`.

Comment: Try `window.open("http://www.somewebpage/" + myTextField.value +  
"/therestofit","this is a new window");`